# Read and Write Circular buffer with Thread synchronisation in iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I've some data which is accumulated in a buffer and I need to read the data when buffer is having data. This i need to do with thread synchronisation. I've worked little with GCD, which I'm failing to do. please help how to do a circular buffer with read and write threads in synchronization.

My Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];       
    readPtr = 0;
    writePtr = 0;
    currentPtr = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{            
            while(YES){
                [self writeToBuffer:buffer[0] withBufferSize:bufferSize];
           }
      });

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{            
            while(YES){
                float* newBuffer;                
                if(currentPtr>512){
                    newBuffer = [self readBuffer];
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
          [self UseBuffer: newBuffer];
           }
      });

}

-(void)writeToBuffer:(float*)Values withBufferSize:(int)bSize{
     [_lock lock];
          for(int i=0;i<bSize;i++){
            if(writePtr>1859){
                writePtr = 0;
            }
            globalBuffer[writePtr] = Values[i];
            writePtr++;
            currentPtr++;
        }
        NSLog(@"Writing");
    [_lock unlock];
}

-(float*)readBuffer{    
    [_lock lock];    
        float rBuffer[512];
        for(int i=0;i<512;i++){
            if(readPtr>1859){
                readPtr = 0;
            }
            rBuffer[i] = globalBuffer[readPtr];
            readPtr++;
            currentPtr--;
        }
        NSLog(@"Reading");
     [_lock unlock]
        return rBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the key points of GCD is that it *completely replaces the need for locks*.   So, if you are mixing GCD and mutex locks it is *typically* a sign that you're doing things wrong or sub-optimally.

A serial queue is, effectively, an exclusive lock on whatever is associated with the serial queue.

There a bunch of problems in your code.

`while (YES) {...}` is going to spin, burning CPU cycles ad infinitum.

The `readBuffer` method is returning a pointer to a stack based buffer.  That won't work.

It isn't really clear what the goal of the code is, but those are some specific issues.

Comment: I need to implement circular buffer using two threads running synchronously  one for writing continuously and one for reading continuously. Please write some code

Comment: @AMIamitekh StackOverflow is neither a "write this code for me" nor a "do my homework for me" site.   I pointed out some very specific problems in your code.  Beyond that, you need to show what errors you are encountering or what symptoms you see.